# Windows 7 BSOD update

Tags: windows-7, bsod, windows-update

I recently updated (on the 17/10/14) my computer on windows 7 and it crashed my computer (with the blue screen of death).  I don't know which update it was as there was 17 to install and 1 optional.  Does anyone have any information as to which update it was just so I don't install that one again?

Comment: share the dmp files from C:\Windows\Minidump so that we can take a look at them to see what is wrong. I know that Update KB2949927 was removed by MS because it causes issues.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to say. There is an error code in the BSOD itself which you can google of course. You must restore your system and try to update it again.